# Video from Set of Images have RGB problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ffmpeg, ipod

HI Guys,

I used ffmpeg for creating video from sequence of Images. Following is My coding.

```
    -(void)imageToMov:(NSString*)videoName imageNumber:(int)imageNumber{


    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath:[Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CoachedFiles/"]] attributes:nil];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath:[Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CoachedFiles/%@/",videoName]] attributes:nil];

    //创建文件
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath:[Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CoachedFiles/%@/%@.mov",videoName,videoName]] contents:nil attributes:nil];
    //[[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath:[Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp/temp.mov"]] contents:nil attributes:nil];

    const char *outfilename = [[Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CoachedFiles/%@/%@.mov",videoName,videoName]]UTF8String];

    UIImage * tempImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp/temp0000.jpeg"]]];

    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtxEnc;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtxEnc;
    AVCodec *pCodecEnc;
    AVFrame *pFrameEnc;
    AVOutputFormat *pOutputFormat;
    AVStream *video_st;

    int i;
    int outbuf_size;
    uint8_t *outbuf;

    int out_size;

    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();

    // auto detect the output format from the name. default is mpeg. 
    pOutputFormat = av_guess_format(NULL, outfilename, NULL);
    if (pOutputFormat == NULL)
        return;

    // allocate the output media context
    pFormatCtxEnc = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (pFormatCtxEnc == NULL)
        return;
    pFormatCtxEnc->oformat = pOutputFormat;
    sprintf(pFormatCtxEnc->filename, "%s", outfilename);

    video_st = av_new_stream(pFormatCtxEnc, 0); // 0 for video

    pCodecCtxEnc = video_st->codec;

    pCodecCtxEnc->codec_id = pOutputFormat->video_codec;
    pCodecCtxEnc->codec_type = CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO;

    // put sample parameters 
    pCodecCtxEnc->bit_rate = 500000;

    // resolution must be a multiple of two 
    pCodecCtxEnc->width = tempImage.size.width;
    pCodecCtxEnc->height = tempImage.size.height;

    // frames per second 
    pCodecCtxEnc->time_base.den = 1;
    pCodecCtxEnc->time_base.num = 1;
    pCodecCtxEnc->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P; 
    pCodecCtxEnc->gop_size = 12; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */

    if (pCodecCtxEnc->codec_id == CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO){
        /* needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow 
         this doesnt happen with normal video, it just happens here as the 
         motion of the chroma plane doesnt match the luma plane */
        pCodecCtxEnc->mb_decision=2;
    }
    // some formats want stream headers to be seperate
    if(!strcmp(pFormatCtxEnc->oformat->name, "mp4") || !strcmp(pFormatCtxEnc->oformat->name, "mov") || !strcmp(pFormatCtxEnc->oformat->name, "3gp"))
        pCodecCtxEnc->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    // set the output parameters (must be done even if no parameters).
    if (av_set_parameters(pFormatCtxEnc, NULL) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    // find the video encoder
    pCodecEnc = avcodec_find_encoder(pCodecCtxEnc->codec_id);
    if (pCodecEnc == NULL)
        return;

    // open it 
    if (avcodec_open(pCodecCtxEnc, pCodecEnc) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (!(pFormatCtxEnc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_RAWPICTURE)) {
        /* allocate output buffer */
        /* XXX: API change will be done */
        outbuf_size = 500000;
        outbuf = av_malloc(outbuf_size);
    }

    pFrameEnc= avcodec_alloc_frame();

    // open the output file, if needed
    if (!(pOutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (url_fopen(&pFormatCtxEnc->pb, outfilename, URL_WRONLY) < 0) {
            //fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s'\n", filename);
            return;
        }
    }

    // write the stream header, if any
    av_write_header(pFormatCtxEnc);

    // Read frames and save frames to disk

    int size = pCodecCtxEnc->width * pCodecCtxEnc->height;
    uint8_t * picture_buf;
    picture_buf = malloc((size * 3) / 2);

    pFrameEnc->data[0] = picture_buf;
    pFrameEnc->data[1] = pFrameEnc->data[0] + size;
    pFrameEnc->data[2] = pFrameEnc->data[1] + size / 4;


    pFrameEnc->linesize[0] = pCodecCtxEnc->width;
    pFrameEnc->linesize[1] = pCodecCtxEnc->width / 2;
    pFrameEnc->linesize[2] = pCodecCtxEnc->width / 2;


    for (i=0;i<imageNumber;i++){
        NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp/temp%04d.jpeg",i];
        NSLog(@"%@",imgName);
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[Utilities documentsPath:imgName]];
        [imgName release];
        //创建avpicture
        AVPicture pict;
        //格式保持bgra,后面是输入图片的长宽
        avpicture_alloc(&pict, PIX_FMT_BGRA, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        //读取图片数据

        CGImageRef cgimage = [image CGImage];
        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgimage);
        CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider); 
        const uint8_t * imagedata = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
        //向avpicture填充数据
        avpicture_fill(&pict, imagedata, PIX_FMT_BGRA, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        //定义转换格式，从bgra转到yuv420
        static int sws_flags =  SWS_FAST_BILINEAR;
        struct SwsContext * img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(image.size.width, 
                                                             image.size.height,
                                                             PIX_FMT_BGRA,
                                                             image.size.width, 
                                                             image.size.height,
                                                             PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                                             sws_flags, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        //转换图象数据格式
        sws_scale (img_convert_ctx, pict.data, pict.linesize,
                   0, image.size.height,
                   pFrameEnc->data, pFrameEnc->linesize);   

        if (pFormatCtxEnc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_RAWPICTURE) {
            /* raw video case. The API will change slightly in the near
             futur for that */
            AVPacket pkt;
            av_init_packet(&pkt);

            pkt.flags |= PKT_FLAG_KEY;
            pkt.stream_index= video_st->index;
            pkt.data= (uint8_t *)pFrameEnc;
            pkt.size= sizeof(AVPicture);

            av_write_frame(pFormatCtxEnc, &pkt);
        } else {
            // encode the image 
            out_size = avcodec_encode_video(pCodecCtxEnc, outbuf, outbuf_size, pFrameEnc);
            // if zero size, it means the image was buffered
            if (out_size != 0) {
                AVPacket pkt;
                av_init_packet(&pkt);

                pkt.pts= pCodecCtxEnc->coded_frame->pts;
                if(pCodecCtxEnc->coded_frame->key_frame)
                    pkt.flags |= PKT_FLAG_KEY;
                pkt.stream_index= video_st->index;
                pkt.data= outbuf;
                pkt.size= out_size;

                // write the compressed frame in the media file
                av_write_frame(pFormatCtxEnc, &pkt);
            }
        }
    }


    // get the delayed frames
    for(; out_size; i++) { 
        out_size = avcodec_encode_video(pCodecCtxEnc, outbuf, outbuf_size, NULL);
        if (out_size != 0) {
            AVPacket pkt;
            av_init_packet(&pkt);

            pkt.pts= pCodecCtxEnc->coded_frame->pts;
            if(pCodecCtxEnc->coded_frame->key_frame)
                pkt.flags |= PKT_FLAG_KEY;
            pkt.stream_index= video_st->index;
            pkt.data= outbuf;
            pkt.size= out_size;

            // write the compressed frame in the media file
            av_write_frame(pFormatCtxEnc, &pkt);
        }
    }

    // Close the codec
    //avcodec_close(pCodecCtxDec); 
    avcodec_close(pCodecCtxEnc);

    // Free the YUV frame
    //av_free(pFrameDec);
    av_free(pFrameEnc);

    av_free(outbuf);

    // write the trailer, if any
    av_write_trailer(pFormatCtxEnc);

    // free the streams
    for(i = 0; i < pFormatCtxEnc->nb_streams; i++) {
        av_freep(&pFormatCtxEnc->streams[i]->codec);
        av_freep(&pFormatCtxEnc->streams[i]);
    }

    if (!(pOutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        /* close the output file */
        //comment out this code to fix the record video issue. Kevin 2010-07-11
        //url_fclose(&pFormatCtxEnc->pb);
    }

    /* free the stream */
    av_free(pFormatCtxEnc);

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:[Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp/"]] isDirectory:NULL]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[Utilities documentsPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp/"]] error:nil];
    }

    //[self MergeVideoFileWithVideoName:videoName];
    [self SaveFileDetails:videoName];


    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Now the Problem is Video is created successfully and the RGB color is greenish. Please notify my mistake on this coding.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on colors but I think your problem might be in the color space you use on your `img_convert_ctx`. You are using `PIX_FMT_BGRA`. That's different colorspace then RGB it's BGR, it has reversed colors. Try using `PIX_FMT_RGBA` instead.